# How to add where clause with two values android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to check password also on where

```
    public Cursor signincheck(String email,String Password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE EMAIL = '" + email + "'";

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;

    }
```

Comment: And use Prepared Statements instead of patching your query together like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use AND

```
String query="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE EMAIL = '" + email + "' AND SECOND_FIELD = '" + your_value_here + "'" ;
```